# How to debug or trace ASP.Net WebApi 2 (5.0) XML serialisation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, debug-symbols

I'm writing ASP.Net WebApi 2 (5.0) application and I have some problems with custom XML serialisation - a POST request hangs after successful deserialisation of request body (a controller is not called). I was trying to debug this but as soon as I exit the deserialisation method debugger doesn't show me any code. The request itself hangs in nowhere (and display 504 in Fiddler after IIS Express process termination).

Further investigation showed there are no pdbs included with WebApi NuGet packages. I searched several debug symbol sources and I've managed to find debug symbols for all WebApi libraries except System.Net.Http.Formatting, which is missing:

```
Assembly title: System.Net.Http.Formatting (88a1bd8d3344b5df289577425c0314e7f521e88a)
Assembly file version: 5.0.11001.0
Assembly version: 5.0.0.0
SymSrv: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb/2F953AE40BC041E5AD078905E6D532FB1/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb (not found)
SymSrv: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb/2F953AE40BC041E5AD078905E6D532FB1/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb (not found)
SymSrv: http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb/2F953AE40BC041E5AD078905E6D532FB1/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb (not found)
```

It looks like pdb for the library is not available at all. If I run the same code under self host, it works perfect (but still not fully debuggable). I switched off all handlers in web.config (under web host), except the one:

```
<handlers>
  <clear />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

and the problem is still there.

Is there any way to debug/trace WebApi serialisation code to understand what's the problem?

Comment: WebApi does model validation (System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider). My model objects are far away from "standard" ones and do not require "standard" validation. The validation itself enters infinite loop on the object graph and POST method never returns. I've completely disabled the validation and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Microsoft Reference Source Code Center](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and see if they're available there yet.

The symbol server is http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols

Follow the instructions to step through the source code of the .Net Framework, and not just your code.

You can also [download local copies](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) of the source code for various releases.

Comment: SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb/2F953AE40BC041E5AD078905E6D532FB1/System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb not found

Comment: If you've followed all the [troubleshooting advice](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/troubleshooting.aspx), then it may be that the symbols are not (yet) available for that version. The symbols often inconsistently lag releases. You can try [downloading a local copy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) of a specific version. I assume you'd want the "4.5Update1" release.

Comment: Followed through the instruction - no success. Actually I don't want sources for the library - a version decompiled by ReSharper is good enough for me. I need just a pdb file. The library I'm looking for is a part of official 5.0 release - it's a little bit weird the symbols are not available for it (but I can find ones for, say, 5.1RC).

Comment: The download includes both symbols and source, and symbols available for local download are not necessarily available on the symbol server, so I've found it's worth downloading the package. Use just the symbols without the source if you choose, but it will use the source automatically when they're installed together.

Comment: There is no symbols for this assembly in the download: SYMSRV:  s:\ThirdParty\RefSrc\Symbols\System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb\2F953AE40BC041E5AD078905E6D532FB1\System.Net.Http.Formatting.pdb not found

Comment: I opened an issue at [CodePlex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1588).

Comment: @AndreyR - They closed the [issue at CodePlex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1588) stating they've published the WebAPI Client 5.0 RTM symbols. I assume that means to symbolsource.org, but they didn't specify.

Comment: It now works (proper pdb is downloaded) - thank you.